# Array of Vectors C++ - curious behaviour when adding elements

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

for google and stackoverflow search could not help me I have no choice but to ask you guys for help.

I would like to use an array of vectors - I know that this array will only have to contain two vectors. Thus

```
vector<double> testVect[1];
```

Now when I want to add an Element to the first vector contained in the array I use

```
testVect[0].push_back(0);
```

So far everything seems ok - unfortunately adding an Element to the first vector somehow also adds the same element (in this case the 0) to the second vector as well.

Could anybody tell me the reason for this kind of behaviour ? (please) - and perhaps a workaround.
Currently I have to use Visual Studio 6 (employer won't install a new compiler - I am already riling up my coworkers :D

Comment: `vector<double> testVect[1];` only makes one vector.  Its an array of one vector, with a maximum index of `0`.  What makes you think there's a second element, or that it would also be affected by the push_back?

Comment: I confused initializing a vector with accesing it's elements. In c++ one starts counting vector elements with 0. Thus if a vector contains 2 elements you would access the first via vector[0]. This is why I thought writing testVect[1] would result in an array of two vectors. Thank you :)

Comment: being downvoted again - this time for no apparent reason ... Sometimes people get confused grr.

Comment: I'd guess the reason is because they think the question is "not well researched".  Not sure I agree.

Comment: I really did research my question first !! Unfortunately it did not even occur to me that I was only working with a 1 elemt array for it seems that warnings were disabled. In my department I am the only person coding C++ and it is my first project. I regularly read stackoverflow "articles" and you guys have already helped me a lot passively <3 <3 :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want two vectors, you should declare:

```
 vector<double> testVect[2];
```

then use `testVect[0]` and `testVect[1]` in your code.

And you should enable all warnings on your compiler.

BTW, you could install a recent Linux distribution, with a recent GCC compiler (e.g. 4.7), and run it as `g++ -Wall -g` it would certainly have warned you if you statically accessed the `testVect` out of bounds, like it seems that you have had.

<sup>Both GNU/Linux and GCC are free, so your manager could be happy.</sup>

Comment: hmm I have no open client and can not install any software without begging the IT department to allow it first :(   Still thanks for the suggestion :)